# In the Survey package for R, how can I get 'svytotal' to only give me "true" values of the variable in the output?

Tags: r, dplyr, survey

**Background:**

I'm working on a large survey and using the terrific `survey` package in `R` to crunch the numbers.

Say that I want to estimate the weighted total of a population broken down by a sex variable, `SEX`. (The variable is coded `1 == MALE` and `2 == FEMALE`.) Here's the code I use to (successfully) get those numbers:

```
svytotal(~I(SEX == 1) + 
         ~I(SEX == 2) ,     
         design = mydesign)
```

**Problem:**

"Problem" is a strong word for this, but the output I get invariably gives me a row for `SEX == 1 == TRUE` *and* `SEX == 1 == FALSE` - and the same for `SEX == 2`. Output looks roughly like so:

```
                                    total   se
I(SEX == 1)FALSE                    30903 1106
I(SEX == 1)TRUE                     32774 1059
I(SEX == 2)FALSE                    32774 1059
I(SEX == 2)TRUE                     30903 1106
```

Like I said, not the end of the world. **But** since I want to be able to pass this easily into a dataframe and export a csv for inclusion directly into `LaTeX`, I'd love to be able to sort out the formatting, only showing me "TRUE", so that I get something like this:

```
                                    total   se
I(SEX == 1)TRUE                     32774 1059
I(SEX == 2)TRUE                     30903 1106
```

Is there a way to do this inside of `Survey`, or will I have to trim things maybe with `dplyr` once I make it a dataframe?

I've tried just asking for `SEX` (heh), like so:

```
svytotal(~SEX,     
         design = mydesign)
```

But that only yields the total across both `1` and `2`.

Thanks!

PS - I got that "I" prefix out of Lumley's (the author of `survey`) book on the package, but I don't know what it does. Excuse the ignorance if it's unnecessary.

Comment: Your code is not reproducible but I think yes you should be able to achieve what you want after converting the output to dataframe.

Comment: `~as.numeric(SEX==1)+as.numeric(SEX==2)` ?